# Cannot read XML File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, touchxml

got a little problem with receiving the contents of a xml file (using TouchXML).

My first query works very well, looks something like this:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:STATION_ID, latitude, longtitude];
CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",rssParser);
```

so this log gives me the complete XML file.

after that, in another method im trying the same:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:WEATHER_URL, [positionInformation objectForKey:@"stationId"]];
CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", rssParser);
```

but the log im getting is (null).
Loggin the URL String gives me the right URL without spaces or something, the URL Log for example looks like this:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:WEATHER_URL, [positionInformation objectForKey:@"stationId"]];
NSLog(@"%@", url);
```

The result in the debugger Console is

```
http://api.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXCurrentObXML.asp?ID=KCASUNNY19
```

looking at this file with my browser seems to be ok. Anybody know whats going wrong?????

I also tried, first to get the content of this URL by stringWithContentsOfURL, but this also not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy was having the same problem: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/15963-problem-initwithcontentsofurl.html.  Looks like the API at Weather Underground is expecting a user-agent and returning a 500 HTTP response when it doesn't see one.  You can use `-initWithData:options:error:` on CXMLDocument to pass the data you get using NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: amazing. thats it! sadly i'm now using an other API for my weather informationn :( but next time :D

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the error argument of initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:. Create an NSerror *object, and pass it in thusly:

```
NSError      *error;
CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:0 error: &error];
```

If you don't get an rssParser object, check that error.

Comment: hmm the error object is:

"Error : Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)"

Comment: do you mean [error userInfo] ? in there is: "{
    NSURL = http://api.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXCurrentObXML.asp?ID=KCASUNNY19;
}"

Answer (score 0):

i copied the content of this xml file to my own server and changed the url path.
this works correcty, so i think there is a problem with reading this ".asp" file.

hmm. but its XML content, strange.

//edit:
i made a little php file on my server that returns the content of the "asp" file:

```
<?php
  echo file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXCurrentObXML.asp?ID=KCASANFR70");
 ?>
```

reading the contents of my script works, but this workaround is not what i want.

oh damn =/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your URL string is properly encoded, so that the question mark gets interpreted as a query?  You might want to look at using `dataUsingEncoding` or `stringUsingEncoding` on your URL before using it to initialize `rssReader`.

Comment: yeah id tried that a few times. first with an encoded url string (which had no effect, because in this url is nothing to encode) and then with a NSString contentfromurl using encoding (i tired ascii and utf8).